# Generate set of Lat/Long for a given Location coordinates that can form a polygon

Tags: c#, maps, latitude-longitude

I need to generate set of Lat/Long that forms a polygon based on Drive Time or Drive distance.  so far I have this idea  in mind.

I can assign 8 - 10 points(Lat/Lon) around the given location and calculate ArcTan2 value between given location to each point and sort points based on the value. I join this points in order to form polygon.

My 2 main questions here.. How do I get 8 - 10 points initially which I get based on drive time range like 0 - 30 miles  or drive time ... 0 - 30 minutes. Is there any good API I can use for free to generate this points ?? I looked into this URL which does exactly what I need but cannot find how it is implemented : http://www.freemaptools.com/radius-around-point.htm

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to match the demo you're showing. Is the question how to calculate a bunch of points forming a circle (with a radius) around a point?

Comment: I m looking for plotting polygon by connected points(Lat/Long). These points.Sorry I sent wrong link. Here is the right link : http://www.freemaptools.com/how-far-can-i-travel.htm.